# equivalent of $.curCSS method in jquery 1.10

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using a library mcdropdown (http://www.givainc.com/labs/) which made use of $.curCSS method. I am using latest jquery library which no longer supports $.curCSS method. As per the documentation, $().css is the equivalent in latest jquery. So I replaced this as below:

For

```
marginTop: parseInt($.curCSS($el[0], "marginTop", true), 10) || 0
```

To

```
marginTop: parseInt($($el[0]).css("marginTop", true), 10) || 0
```

This conversion did not work for me although there are no errors in console log . What is the correct conversion for above code using $().css method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you pass a 2nd argument to `.css()` it attempts to apply that value. if you simply want to extrapolate the value, you should use:

```
parseInt($(el[0]).css('marginTop'), 10)
```